# Adding translation strings for iOS in Weblate failes for the 1st commit

Tags: ios, localization, weblate

Everytime we add a new translation string in Weblate via Web-GUI the iOS string is without quotes.

`drawer_collect_enroll_i=Select what you want`

but it should be

`"drawer_collect_enroll_i"="Select what you want"`

If I commit a 2nd time everything is corrected!!

Any solutions for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've also reported it at https://github.com/WeblateOrg/weblate/issues/4151, let's deal with the bug there...

Comment: Thx Michal for your fast solution